# Installation appears to be corrupt [Unsupported] - Visual Studio Code

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, installation

I have a problem with my Visual Studio Code. I have a popup that appears in the bottom right corner, to inform that my VS Code is damaged. So this week I uninstalled my VS Code from Windows. I then went to the official Visual Studio Code website to get the installation executable. Once done, I do the installation, everything works again correctly, then 5 min after, there is a new popup.

Is there a solution that allows me to fix this?

I have a pc on Windows 10 64bits.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**Short answer** - try vs-code extension [Fix VSCode Checksums](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lehni.vscode-fix-checksums).

After installation, open *command palette* and run '*Fix Checksums: Apply*'. 
Now, just restart your vs-code.

 *or*

Alternatively, open *command palette* and write '*Developer: Reload Window*'.

That's it.

This fixes the issue for me as well (If you ever have any problems/doubts and wanted to undo what you just did, open *command palette* and execute '*Fix Checksums: Restore*').

---

**Details** - I was having the same issue after installing 'SynthWave 84 theme' and 'Enable Neon Dreams' (that glow effect), as mentioned by answers above.

I searched for it and even though vs-code documentation suggested to re-install the VS Code (as mentioned in the second answer), I was willing to search for another possible solution.

so, I found [this section](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RobbOwen.synthwave-vscode#to-remove-corruption-warning-and-unsupported-from-title-bar) on 'SynthWave 84' extension official page.

thus, just wanted to add another possibility to this question, which may help someone.

I will be following this and if it causes any issue in VS Code updates or anything related, I will provide an update.

JFYI - I am on macOS Catalina, but I am sure it will be the same for windows as well and vs-code September 2020 (version 1.50)

Comment: The theme is probably the issue. [Visual Studio Code FAQ](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_installation-appears-to-be-corrupt-unsupported) says that "[...] some extensions directly modify (patch) the VS Code product in such a way that is semi-permanent (until the next update) and this can cause hard to reproduce issues." Also, there is no "Reload Windows" option for me. There *is* "Reload Window", though. I had to reload every window separately. After doing this, you will also have to re-update Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 Yes, you are right, Theme is changing the product code directly ending up the checksum mismatch. But if somebody loves the theme this hassle is worth it.

Thanks for catching the mistake, let me remove the 's' from 'Reload Windows'.

If you have multiple windows opened, you can close all at once and reopen VS code or reload individual windows as you did.

Lastly, (for me) I didn`t have to re-update the VS code to get rid of that 'UnSupported' error in title and error notification, but it's always great to update it.

Comment: Actually, what I meant is the issue was fixed after reloading the window (even the title bar), but the update was not applied.

Comment: I got this issue from the SynthWave theme. This fixed it 

Comment: the Fix Checksums: Apply worked for me, sadly after i uninstalled the theme, not willing to install it back

Comment: awesome dude this worked for me! By the way, I'm working on mac Monterey. But however you apply checksum command after you set up the theme [background](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shalldie.background) extension

Comment: I had to run the cmd 5 times to make the error go away.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you installed an unsupported theme or extension, i.e. JS CSS loader and themes like SynthWave '84, this theme and extension are not supported by Visual Studio Code or change protected files that VScode uses.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, indeed I recently installed the SynthWave '84 theme, or I had to modify something in the .json package.

Comment: VS code doesn't natively support text effects and as a result, the glow is experimental. It's likely to be buggy and, whilst it looks rad, it isn't intended for extended use. To enable the glow, the extension has to modify the internal files of VS Code, so use with caution. Should something go wrong, you can disable the glow by following the instructions below. If for any reason you can't open VS Code, you can fix the issue with a fresh install of VS Code.
If you do decide use the glow effect, you do so at your own risk. Bring your Sunglasses. Here be (laser)dragons.

Comment: yes, so i recommand uninstalling the theme and installing this one https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nadim-vscode.infinity-dark-theme

Comment: @Grezor how did you resolve this issue. I'm facing the same issue too!

Comment: @SagarKulkarni just uninstall the unsppourted themes or plugins

Comment: Nope, it didn't work I had to reinstall VSCode......TEDIOUS!

Comment: @NadimAlAbdou that theme is not really anything like synthwave `84. not my cup of tea.

Thanks for the answer. I will risk destruction at the hands of this fancy vscode theme.

Answer (score 4):

I got this issue after installing "SynthWave 84" extension.

[Official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_installation-appears-to-be-corrupt-unsupported) is recommending the reinstallation of VSCode!

However, Took the following steps to resolve this issue as I never wanted to reinstall VSCode!

- Uninstall "SynthWave 84" extension and this restarts VSCode
- Restart VSCode manually again by closing all the VSCode projects
- Update VSCode (Click on Settings -> Check for Updates) and this restarts VSCode.

Voila, the issue got resolved without having to reinstall VSCode.

Comment: [github.com/robb0wen/synthwave-vscode#to-remove-corruption-warning-and-unsupported-from-title-bar](https://github.com/robb0wen/synthwave-vscode#to-remove-corruption-warning-and-unsupported-from-title-bar)

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. just uninstalled Synthwave theme.
and simply overwrite your vscode setup.
and you still install synthwave, but make sure NOT to enable Neon dream.

Answer (score -2):

It is possible your anti-virus software is removing necessary vscode files.

Try navigating to your anti-virus software settings and
finding the quarantined files.

If there are vscode files listed restore them.